# Need a superscript for x raise to b

Tags: iphone, objective-c, superscript

I need a superscript for displaying x raise to b.

I was able to display x raise to 2 (i.e. x square),
also x raise to 3 (i.e. x cube)..

But now I need to display x raise to b using superscript..

Please help..

Comment: How do you display x^2 and x^3?

Comment: using superscript \u00B2 and \u00B3 respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `\u1D47` (ᵇ) if the font supports.

Note that in Unicode this is not really intended as a "superscript b", but is a phonetic symbol. Find a rich text label library for the proper solution.

```
a = ᵃ = \u1d43 (modifier letter small a)
b = ᵇ = \u1d47 (modifier letter small b)
c = ᶜ = \u1d9c (modifier letter small c)
d = ᵈ = \u1d48 (modifier letter small d)
e = ᵉ = \u1d49 (modifier letter small e)
f = ᶠ = \u1da0 (modifier letter small f)
g = ᵍ = \u1d4d (modifier letter small g)
h = ʰ = \u02b0 (modifier letter small h)
i = ⁱ = \u2071 (superscript latin small letter i)
j = ʲ = \u02b2 (modifier letter small j)
k = ᵏ = \u1d4f (modifier letter small k)
l = ˡ = \u02e1 (modifier letter small l)
m = ᵐ = \u1d50 (modifier letter small m)
n = ⁿ = \u207f (superscript latin small letter n)
o = ᵒ = \u1d52 (modifier letter small o)
p = ᵖ = \u1d56 (modifier letter small p)
q = n/a
r = ʳ = \u02b3 (modifier letter small r)
s = ˢ = \u02e2 (modifier letter small s)
t = ᵗ = \u1d57 (modifier letter small t)
u = ᵘ = \u1d58 (modifier letter small u)
v = ᵛ = \u1d5b (modifier letter small v)
w = ʷ = \u02b7 (modifier letter small w)
x = ˣ = \u02e3 (modifier letter small x)
y = ʸ = \u02b8 (modifier letter small y)
z = ᶻ = \u1dbb (modifier letter small z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using html `<sup>` tags in your text string and then having it displayed using [NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML) available from github.